# Facebook Timeline RSS Feed

Tags: facebook

Do you think that the new Facebook timelines still uses RSS since I had an application that parsed RSS from Facebook but for new pages I cannot manage to get an Rss feed. Any one has an idea where to get an RSS Feed for the new timeline ?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is an article on how to to do this.](http://ooiks.com/blog/how-to-2/get-facebook-fans-page-news-feed-rss-feed-atom-feed)

Answer (score 2):

I actually want to do the same but from what im reading fb remove it :/

http://thehappyhubber.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Add-your-RSS-Feed-to-Your-Facebook-Page